# Split DateTime string, ArrayFormula, Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a 'Date' 'at' 'Time' string in A1, for example:

> A1: December 27, 2013 at 08:24AM

I would like to have Date and Time in B1 and C1, for example:

> B1: 12/27/2013
>   C1: 8:24:00

How to split the A1 into B1 and C1? 
And what if I have a new row like

> A2: January 02, 2014 at 08:28AM

then

> B2: 01/02/2014
>   C2: 08:28:00

can be generated automatically?

It seems I can achieve this via "ArrayFormula" and "REGEXEXTRACT", but after lots of search, I still can not find the formula to apply to my spreadsheet.

Comment: Why do you create an account over at Web Applications, and collect your rep: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/54645/29140

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra It is not done by me, this question should be migrated by the stack overflow web administrator.

Comment: @pnuts no, it should be without ','

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way; in B1:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A:A),REGEXREPLACE(A:A,"(.*?) at (.*)",{"$1","$2"})+0,))`

and then format the B column as Date and C column as Time.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your quick response! It works perfectly with your formula.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler to select the two cells, Data > Split text into columns... with Custom Separator of `at` then format to suit.